# Can't open Opera all of a sudden

Tags: permissions, opera

I've been running Opera on one of my machines for about a year without any issues.

When turning on my laptop this morning and trying to open Opera I get the following error message.

```
Can't open user profile directory, because you lack sufficient
privileges. You might want to contact the administrator of this
machine.
```

I did run a software update the night before and if I remember correctly it did **NOT** update Opera.

I have my home folder on a separate partition and I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I was surprised to see that a google search of the error message did not turn up any useful results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the permissions with `ls -ld ~/.opera`.

Comment: did you attempt to open opera with root?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed after I ran a software update. This time, Opera was updated.

But before being able to run software update I had to clear some space from my root partitition, and I think this was like the real culprit.